# KeyedDecodingContainer not being called which is in a different package

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, jsondecoder

The below code is in swift package manager which has handling of JSON decoder.

```swift
//MyJSONPackage

extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
  func func decode(_ type: Bool.Type, forKey key: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>.Key) throws -> Bool
{
/// This is not being called from Main Project.
return try decodeIfPresent(type, forKet: key) ?? .init()
}

}
```

The code which expects to call this is a different project (named "MainProject"), which uses the above package manager.

Is there a way for that project to make sure it calls the `KeyedDecodingContainer.decode` of `MyJSONPackage` instead of the main project? Or how to enforce `MainProject` for a specific block of code uses
`KeyedDecodingContainer.decode` available in `MyJSONPackage`

Answer (score 1):

Found `public` keyword was missing.

It won't throw any error if public is missing and it would provide the default implementation in existing project.

This could happen with other extension as well, if `public` keyword is missing and the project which calls the package manager provides a default implementation.

```swift
//MyJSONPackage

extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
// public accessor was MISSING.
  public func decode(_ type: Bool.Type, forKey key: KeyedDecodingContainer<K>.Key) throws -> Bool
{
/// This is not being called from Main Project.
return try decodeIfPresent(type, forKet: key) ?? .init()
}

}
```